# Checking if a JSON key is empty before adding to constructor

Tags: java, android, json

I am looping through my JSONobjects and extracting values putting them into a constructor for an array. It is working fine, but on the second loop the next object has an empty value for "description" and is causing an error, `org.json.JSONException: No value for description` which I believe is causing the code to exit the loop, and create no more ArrayList entries, hence I only see one result. I've tried using an if block to check .lenth(), isEmpty(), and setting the String to another value but it isn't working. Here is a code snippet.

```
public static ArrayList<Books> extractBooks(String jsonString) {
    ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
    String emptyDescription = null;

    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = baseJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++) {
            JSONObject currentBook = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject items = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            JSONObject imageLinks = items.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
            String title = items.getString("title");
            String author = items.getString("authors");
            String published = items.getString("publishedDate");
            //Todo: fix null description string if no desc available
            String description = items.getString("description");

            if (description.equals("{}")){
                description = "No info.";
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "if desc block: " + description);
            }
            String image = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");
            Bitmap bitmap = extractImages(image);

            Books book = new Books(title, author, bitmap, published, description);
            books.add(book);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing JSON book results", e);
    }

    return books;
}
```

Comment: share your josn string.

Comment: JsonObject.has("description")..You can user like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.json.JSONException: No value for description

You should check **Json** **[has](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))**. **`boolean has (String name)`**

> Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. 
>   NULL

```
if (items.has("description")) 
 {
    String description= items.getString("description"));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block like below:

```
String description = "";
try {
   description = items.getString("description");
}catch(JSONException e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use isNull for checking

`json.isNull( "fieldName" )`

Answer (score 0):

you can also check if your JSONObject has the given Key https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.has(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) method to check whether it has the value or not.

Also consider learning about [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or any other JSON converters.

Answer (score 0):

you could use  `boolean has(String key)` to test if the object has a particular key or use one of the `opt` methods that return always a default value instead of throwing an exception. E.g.

```
String description = items.optString("description", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a no `key` for a `description` for the second loop.  then you have to check like below

```
if (items.has("description")){
                // get your description key data here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you post your response it looks like value for description is empty or there is no key for description

to check it you can simply add

```
String description = items.optString("description");
```

then you can check description is null or empty

```
 if(description ==null||description.equals("")){
    description ="";
}else{

}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, each result has a "description" key but one but has no data for the key. It's the second result, which is preventing any other results being returned. Here is the JSON URL

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=10

Comment: you can add above code just in if part add description ="";  it will prevent code from exception

Answer (score 0):

best way to check null or empty both use textUtil java class

```
           String descriptionVariable ="";

         if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(description )){

       descriptionVariable = items.getString("description");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check  JSONObject  which you recevied from web server

```
     JSONObject baseJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        try {
            if(baseJsonObject!=null){
                JSONArray jsonArray = baseJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject currentBook = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  if (currentBook.has("description")) {
                String description = json.getString("description"));
             }


                }
            }else{
                //Server is Uncharable
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```